File upload is not working with Node.js clusters, socket.io and Multer
I am working on an application that was written in Node.js express with socket.io and Multer.During file upload i got error as unexpected end of form.
This is my code
master.js
require("dotenv").config();

const cluster = require("cluster");
const logger = require("./logger");
const http = require("http");

const numCPUs = require("os").cpus().length;
const { setupMaster, setupWorker } = require("@socket.io/sticky");
const { setupPrimary } = require("@socket.io/cluster-adapter");

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  logger.info(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

  const httpServer = http.createServer();

  // setup sticky sessions
  setupMaster(httpServer, {
    loadBalancingMethod: "least-connection",
  });

  // setup connections between the workers
  setupPrimary();

  // needed for packets containing buffers (you can ignore it if you only send plaintext objects)
  // Node.js < 16.0.0
  cluster.setupMaster({
    serialization: "advanced",
  });

  httpServer.listen(process.env.SERVER_PORT);

  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on("exit", (worker) => {
    logger.warn(`Worker ${worker.id} died`);
    cluster.fork();
  });
} else {
  require("./worker");
}

worker.js
const http = require("http");
const cluster = require("cluster");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

const { createAdapter } = require("@socket.io/cluster-adapter");

require("dotenv").config();
const logger = require("./logger");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const pg = require("pg"),
  session = require("express-session"),
  pgSession = require("connect-pg-simple")(session);

const { setupWorker } = require("@socket.io/sticky");

const sessionMiddleware = session({
  store: new pgSession({
    pool: new pg.Pool(), // Connection pool
    tableName: "session",
    pruneSessionRandomizedInterval: false,
    pruneSessionInterval: 20,
  }),
  secret: process.env.MY_KEY,
  resave: false,
  rolling: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: { secure: false, maxAge: 6000 * 1000 }, // 1 min
});

const app = express();

app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    parameterLimit: 100000,
    limit: "6mb",
    extended: true,
  }),
);

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "6mb" }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(sessionMiddleware);

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(express.static("/UI"));
app.use("/api", require("./api"));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("./UI/index.html");
});


const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

const io = new Server(httpServer);

// use the cluster adapter
io.adapter(createAdapter());

// setup connection with the primary process
setupWorker(io);

const workerId = cluster.worker.id;
logger.info("Worker Id", workerId);


/* httpServer.listen(process.env.SERVER_PORT, () => {
   logger.info(`Server listening to port ${process.env.SERVER_PORT}`);
 });*/

api.js
const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, files, cb) {
    cb(null, FILE_PATH);
  },

  // By default, multer removes file extensions so let's add them back
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, FILE_PATH);
  },
});
router
  .route("/upload")
  .post((req, res, next) => {
    let returnObj = {
      ok: false,
    };

    try {
      let upload = multer({ storage }).single("file");
      upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err instanceof multer.MulterError || err) {
          returnObj.error = err;
          res.send(returnObj);
          logger.error(`file upload multer error: ${err}`);
          return;
        }
        next();
      });
    } catch (err) {
      returnObj.error = err;
      res.send(returnObj);
      logger.error(`file upload multer error: ${err}`);
    }
  };

I am also using HAproxy load balancer
frontend www 
  bind *:80
  
  acl is_multipart hdr_sub(Content-Type) -i multipart/form-data
  
  use_backend upload_backend if is_multipart
  
  default_backend NodeServer

backend upload_backend
   balance roundrobin
   server node2 127.0.0.1:3000 check


backend NodeServer
   balance roundrobin
   option httpchk
   cookie SERVER insert indirect nocache
   server node3 127.0.0.1:3000 check 
   server node4 127.0.0.1:3000 check 
   server node1 127.0.0.1:3000 check 
   timeout connect 10s
   timeout server 3600s

with the above code if i try to upload the file i got an error as "unexpected end of form". However if i change the code if i uncomment the code in worker.js and start listening in workers then file upload is working but socket is not connecting to client. socket.io response is 400 bad request "Session ID unknown". I do not want to use any other middleware like socket-redis or pg.

can we redirect multi-part form request to any one dedicated worker and how?
